# What do you call a photo taken after winning the lottery?

Tags: word-request

> The mugshot of his face looked funny, the one they took of him after
> getting his lottery winnings.

I think mugshot only applies to people who get jailed, but I am wondering if there's a word similar to mugshot but for lottery winners.

Comment: If you look up definitions of _mugshot_, many dictionaries say that it refers _typically_ to a photo taken when a person is arrested - not that that is the only possible meaning.

Comment: Fun fact. In the USA, the formal portrait of a student in a high-school yearbook/annual is frequently called a mugshot. My wife was a yearbook advisor for many years, so I know this practice is common.

Comment: A *mugshot* is a photo primarily used for identification, as they appear in yearbooks, lineup books, and passports.  A mugshot is generally chest and head only without scenery.  When someone wins the lottery the associated photo is of them beaming and holding a giant check with lots of zeros on it.  That is not a *mugshot*.  There is no word for it.  I think referring to it as *the picture they took of him with his winnings check* is a pretty good descriptor.

Comment: The word "mugshot" is often used humorously for any photo: it's considered funny, partly because you're alluding to mugshots being ugly (hence suggesting the person looks ugly) and partly because it's considered funny to pretend that somebody is in jail or another humiliating situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that mugshot in this context is odd. The entire sentence reads slightly wrong in English. I might say:

The picture/photo/snapshot they took of him after he received/collected his lottery winnings was weird, his face looked funny in it/the picture.